# Espresso Android: Click on Image under sub Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am using Espresso for Android Test and want to click on the imageView under the Linear Layout, the problem is that this Linear Layout do not have Unique ID

Here is the XML:

```
--LinearLayout (This one have Unique ID)
      --LinearLayout1 (No ID)
             --RelativeLayout (No ID)
                  --TextView
                  --ImageView
             --RelativeLayout (No ID)
                  --TextView
                  --ImageView
      --LinearLayout2 (No ID)
             --RelativeLayout (No ID)
                  --TextView
                  --ImageView
             --RelativeLayout (No ID)
                  --TextView
                  --ImageView
      --LinearLayout3 (No ID)
             --RelativeLayout (No ID)
                  --TextView
                  --ImageView
              -RelativeLayout (No ID)
                  --TextView
                  --ImageView
```

In other words, only the top level LinearLayout have an ID but underneath it there are 3 more LinearLayout which have no ID, so it is difficult to identify this. The text and image view is dynamic. I just want to click on the first or second image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rely on `TextView` text which must be unique in the layout and use `hasSibling()`:

```
onView(hasSibling(withText("TextView_unique_text"))).perform(click());
```

or

```
onView(allOf(instanceOf(ImageView.class), hasSibling(withText("TextView_unique_text"))))
    .perform(click());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes hasSibling() worked for me:

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(allOf(withId(R.id.horizontal), hasSibling(withText("Text")))).atPosition(2).onChildView(withId(R.id.image)).perform(click());
```